# Unable to create Hive table, flaky metastore connections

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr

I'm following [this blog post](http://aws.mannem.me/?p=1462) that partitions S3 Access Logs by date using Hive and EMR.  I was able to run this script against a small bucket of access logs okay, but table creation on top of a large bucket (~ 1.5 TB) fails with the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

I looked through the hive logs, but nothing stand out: /mnt/var/log/hive.  Not sure what the problem is as this error is pretty generic.  I'm pretty much following the blog post verbatim and the script errors out on the following after 10 or 15 minutes

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Accesslogs(....
```

**Update: I found more log info and also ran Hive in debug mode.  EMR gets intermittent connection failures to the metastore then finally fails**

> .........
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221) [hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-5.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) [hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-5.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           ... 33 more
>   2017-12-10T15:18:18,718 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(506)) - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
>   2017-12-10T15:18:19,719 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(392)) - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://ip-172-50-31-107.ec2.internal:9083
>   2017-12-10T15:18:19,719 WARN  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(472)) - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226) ~[hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:465) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.reconnect(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:335) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:163) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source) [?:?]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2303) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source) [?:?]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:854) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:869) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) [hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) [hive-cli-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221) [hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-5.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) [hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-5.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[hive-exec-2.3.1-amzn-0.jar:2.3.1-amzn-0]
>           ... 33 more
>   2017-12-10T15:18:19,720 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(506)) - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
>   2017-12-10T15:18:20,721 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(392)) - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://ip-172-50-31-107.ec2.internal:9083
>   2017-12-10T15:18:20,721 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(466)) - Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
>   2017-12-10T15:18:20,795 INFO  [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: hive.metastore (HiveMetaStoreClient.java:open(519)) - Connected to metastore.
>   2017-12-10T15:18:28,013 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:18:28,014 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:19:28,014 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:19:28,014 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:20:28,014 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:20:28,014 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:21:28,015 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:21:28,015 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:22:28,015 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:22:28,015 DEBUG [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper([])]: conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:closeIdleConnections(401)) - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
>   2017-12-10T15:22:44,472 ERROR [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:failed(639)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:864)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:869)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
>           at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>           at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
>           at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
>           at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
>           at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1185)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2372)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:93)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:737)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:725)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2303)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.createTable(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:854)
>           ... 22 more
>
> 2017-12-10T15:22:44,472 ERROR [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(1126)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>   2017-12-10T15:22:44,472 DEBUG [e74af478-3227-4bf9-9fde-74d8babcf5f0 main([])]: ql.Driver (DriverContext.java:shutdown(132)) - Shutting down query CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Accesslogs(
>     BucketOwner string,
>     Bucket string,
>     RequestDateTime string,
>     RemoteIP string,
>     Requester string,
>     RequestID string,
>     Operation string,
>     Key string,
>     RequestURI_operation string,
>     RequestURI_key string,
>     RequestURI_httpProtoversion string,
>     HTTPstatus string,
>     ErrorCode string,
>     BytesSent string,
>     ObjectSize string,
>     TotalTime string,
>     TurnAroundTime string,
>     Referrer string,
>     UserAgent string,
>     VersionId string)
>   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
>   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
>    'serialization.format' = '1',

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, Hive is trying to do something which is fast on a filesystem (recursive treewalk, rename) which keels over when it gets to s3 and all these things are faked in the client.

Consider filing a JIRA against Hive on this; include any logs server side you can too, and try some different scaled files to see when things fail.